# Why cannot I choose MySQL as database type in the installation page?

Tags: database, installation

I downloaded the Drupal archive and extracted it on the dedicated server. In cPanel, I created a MySQL database, but when I try to install Drupal, in the *Database configuration* page, I can only choose between PostgreSQL and SQLite as database type; I cannot choose MySQL.

> [image: screenshot]

Why did it happen? How do I fix it?

Comment: Check that your PHP has been installed with the proper MySQL extensions

Comment: @Jaypan which extension should be chosen?

Comment: `pdo_mysql` should be enough

Comment: @Clive `pdo_mysql` are not on my host but I found `pdo_sqlsrv` but when I checked checkbox it didn't change anything.
See screenshot:http://i.piccy.info/i9/6e7ed1b4cfdc764a6563540d6e874159/1591640282/106033/1382605/Screenshot_2.jpg

Comment: "`pdo_mysql` are not on my host" <-- it's required to use MySQL. You'll have to rebuild PHP with this extension, or you can use sqllite, since it is already installed.

Comment: Try `nd_pdo_mysql`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Create a **info.php** file and upload it to your server :

```php
 php_info()
```

2. upload the file to your server is docroot then visit the URL **http://youdomain.com/info.php**
3. search for **pdo_mysql** and it should be enabled if it does not exist  contact the server admin and tell him to enable the **pdo_mysql** (https://serverfault.com/questions/471282/how-enable-pdo-mysql) :
   [image]

> in your case I think you have just the **pgsql** and **SQLite** PDO enabled